# for in converting str to list why?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, glob, sequences

I'm currently building a script to find image sequences and group them together.. my problem is when I get the file names and go to run a "for in" on them they turn into lists... why?? This is my code:

```
import os, glob

path = r'C:\Users\manley\Desktop\testSeq'

for my_file in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.jpg') ):

    (dirName, fileName) = os.path.split(my_file)
    (fileBaseName, fExt) = os.path.splitext(fileName)
    #print fileName

    pathLists = fileName
    pathList1 = []
    pathList2 = []

    #print pathList
    #print fileName

    for fName in pathLists:
        print fName
```

The filename = rightSide_020_30.0001.jpg

when the fName prints I get a list of each letter...
How do I get the fName to perserve the fileName as a str?

Comment: This code confuses me. Why do you need to do the inner `for..in` over a list that will only ever have one item in it?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that in the folder I'm searching there are different types of file sequences.. so I need to separate them. Thats what the next step is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little unclear to me but in your case each letter is getting printed because your doing this

```
>>> mylist = "abc"
>>> for m in mylist:
...    print m
...
a
b
c
>>>
```

Your `pathlist` is a string.

I think you meant to do this:

```
pathList1 = []
pathList1.append(filename)

for fname in pathList1:
          print fname
```

Comment: ah, your right. Thats what I wanted to do. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 5):

You should only do this:

```
import os, glob

path = r'C:\Users\manley\Desktop\testSeq'

for my_file in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.jpg') ):

    (dirName, fileName) = os.path.split(my_file)
    print fileName
```

There's no need for more code.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that I was trying to separate different file types. There aren't just jpgs there. So the second part was starting to do that.. but thank you for taking your time and helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

`pathLists = fileName`  which is a string... representing one file name... when you `for` over a string, it yields each character...